# aws lambda timeout doing neptune query

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm very new to AWS Neptune and gremlin and trying to get my lambda function to run a simple query but they are hanging and the lambda function times out before I get a response.
I set up the connection according to AWS docs but having a hard time getting any queries to execute and return data.  I have an EC2 instance that I can connect to the database through the gremlin console and can run queries fine there, I only have issues running them in my lambda function.

connection.ts

```js
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const {getUrlAndHeaders} = require('gremlin-aws-sigv4/lib/utils');
const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;

let conn = null;
let g = null;

export function connection(){
    const getConnectionDetails = () => {
        if (process.env['USE_IAM'] == 'true'){
           return getUrlAndHeaders(
               process.env['NEPTUNE_ENDPOINT'],
               process.env['NEPTUNE_PORT'],
               {},
               '/gremlin',
               'wss'); 
        } else {
            const database_url = 'wss://' +  "my database endpoing" + ':' + "8182" + '/gremlin';
            return { url: database_url, headers: {}};
        }      
      };

      const createRemoteConnection = () => {
        const { url, headers } = getConnectionDetails();
        
        const c = new DriverRemoteConnection(
            url, 
            { 
                mimeType: 'application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json', 
                headers: headers 
            });  
    
         c._client._connection.on('close', (code, message) => {
                 console.info(`close - ${code} ${message}`);
                 if (code == 1006){
                     console.error('Connection closed prematurely');
                     throw new Error('Connection closed prematurely');
                 }
             });  
        
         return c;       
      };
    
      const createGraphTraversalSource = (conn) => {
        return traversal().withRemote(conn);
      };
    
      if (conn == null){
        console.info("Initializing connection")
        conn = createRemoteConnection();
        g = createGraphTraversalSource(conn);
      }

      return g;
      
}
```

index.ts

```js
import {connection} from "./connection"
export async function handler(event, context): Promise<any> {

  const g = connection()
  let result;
  console.log("before query") // this gets called
  const user =  await g.V('1').values("name").next(); // hangs here
  console.log("after query")  //This never gets executed
  return user
}
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does your Lambda function have access to the Neptune VPC? What do you have the Lambda timeout set to? Perhaps try increasing it a bit just to see if that helps at all.

Comment: I think I did need to give it access to the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I needed to add the lambda function to the same VPC as my database